# PHP Long Curl Request

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm doing a Curl request to get a JSON file from a provider and the returned JSON file is huge.

If I run it in a browser, the response is a 21Mb string. When I'm running this request with Curl, It doesn't just take a lot of time but it also ends with a `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted` error.

One way to solve it would be to add `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` to my code (I already did it with 256 but it's still not enough...).
I was wondering if there is another way to get that data faster?

I know it's not a memory leak, it's just that the response is huge.
I don't want to increase the memory limit, I know it's gonna work but I'd like to know if it's possible to get that data faster, even if I have to save it into a file to read it after.

Thanks!

Comment: There are ways to stream JSON and therefore save memory, but you cannot speed up the curl request. If you can you should implement some sort of pagination on the sender side.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Unfortunately I don't have any control on the provider's server :(

Comment: You could download the response into a file and then parse the file with something like [this](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser)

Answer (score 0):

well, JSON is UTF-8, and most UTF-8 data compresses very, very well.

now the first and easiest optimization, is to enable curl's built-in compression transfer, by doing `CURLOPT_ENCODING=>''` , by setting it to emptystring, you tell curl to offer all the compression encodings that curl was compiled with (which usually includes `gzip` and `deflate`) - and gzip in particular, when applied to jsons, can easily compress it down by a factor of 6-7, that should be a huge speedup in retrieving the json, provided that your libcurl is compiled with gzip support, and the target server supports gzip compressed trasnfer-encoding.

now, if you want to optimize even harder, the next step is to figure out what is the strongest compression supported by the target server, and implement that compression manually. lets say for example, that the strongest compression supported by your target server, is LZMA2 , in the `xz` format. then you'd manually set the header `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array('Accept-Encoding: xz')` , and after curl has downloaded it, decompress it manually, for example with https://github.com/payden/php-xz

- xz, while not commonly supported in most web servers, offers even better compression than gzip, and can compress JSON's utf-8 up to a factor of 10 in some tests

but it probably isn't xz, you should figure out the target server's strongest supported compression, whatever it is, and stick to it.